# how to break long text into multiple line in vu

Tags: vue.js, text

I am showing a line in vue as shown below.

However the text is long to show in one line, wondering how to break one line into multiples lines automatically

```
<span class="text-xs">Make.Your.Case.With.These.8.Law.Firm.Interview.Questions.and.Answers</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `span`'s width is already limited, you can add `word-break: break-all;` styles to `span`, so no matter how long you word is, if it's not fit in the container, it will break into multiple lines, ignoring all of the language rules.